# How do I search number fields in Google AppEngine with less than or equals?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

These queries won't work:

```
INFO: Searching with query:  year:(<=2008 OR  2011) 
INFO: Searching with query:  year:(<=2008)
```

#### Code

```
    log.info("Searching with query: " + q);
    try {
        Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(q);
```

#### Exception

```
INFO: Searching with query:  year:(<=2008 OR  2011) 
line 1:7 no viable alternative at input '<='
Nov 08, 2013 3:36:03 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: Unable to parse query:  year:(<=2008 OR  2011) 
com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchQueryException: Unable to parse query:  year:(<=2008 OR  2011) 
at com.google.appengine.api.search.checkers.QueryChecker.checkQueryParses(QueryChecker.java:44)
at com.google.appengine.api.search.checkers.QueryChecker.checkQuery(QueryChecker.java:28)
at com.google.appengine.api.search.Query$Builder.setQueryString(Query.java:91)
at com.google.appengine.api.search.Query$Builder.build(Query.java:107)
at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.searchAsync(IndexImpl.java:378)
at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.search(IndexImpl.java:479)
```

#### Version

appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.6.jar

#### Reference

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings

Comment: Isn't `<=2008` the same as `<2009`? Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like syntax is wrong. Based on the reference you provided, since

`"weather=stormy"
"weather: stormy"` are equivalent, try:

`"year<=2008 OR year=2011"`

(assuming that is what you intended in your example).

Comment: `"Color = (red OR blue)"     You can use parentheses and the logical operator OR to specify a list of alternate field values.`

Comment: but you are using `:` and `<=` for `year` at the same time in your query, it's like writing `year = <= 2008`